# symfony 2 slashes at end of url

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I am starting to work with Symfony2 and so far I like the Framework very much. I only got one problem, all URLs get a slash added at the end after every link click.

Example:

I am on: http://symblog.dev/app_dev.php

now the home button points to http://symblog.dev/app_dev.php/

when i click it I am on: http://symblog.dev/app_dev.php/ 

and there is another slash at the end of the home URL, so it is now: 
http://symblog.dev/app_dev.php//

this keeps going as often as I click the button, what causes things like the debug toolbar to crash because the ajax url does not match with multiple slashes etc. It occurs on every URL on the site not just the debug toolbar ajax.

I hope someone got an idea what the problem might be.

**Environment**

- vagrant debian 7 vm
- apache2, php 5.5, OPcache, hhvm
- mysql 5.5
- code lies in a shared folder with all permissions, host system is win 8.1

**Screenshot:** http://picload.org/image/cgardll/screenshot2014-08-2320.14.47.png

// please excuse misspellings etc. since i don't speak english natively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'de recommend reading the documentation on routing for symfony2:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

This should give you a good idea of how the routing in the framework works so you don't run into this issue in the future.

Hope this was helpful.

EDIT:
Take a look at this as well
http://blog.christian-baer.com/index.php/trailing-slash-in-symfony-route/

Comment: Yeah I already read the Docu about Routing, but the problem already occured in the demo bundle, and i assume the routes there are fine, but i'll take another look.

Comment: I've added another resource to look at, hope that helps

Comment: For future readers, writing a catch-all controller (i.e. is the last controller in the routing config) that redirects to the non-slash version of a URL can be a solution. In the routing docs, specifically see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html